# How to delay a function call counting the execution time of the function itself

Tags: python, multithreading, time

I'm trying to loop a specific function **exactly** after a specified amount of time.
I pondered using time.sleep() for this, however the time module does not count the runtime of the function itself.
For example:

```
def function(*args, **kwargs):
   ## Some processing happens here that takes 0.9 seconds
   time.sleep(1)
```

This function would take 1.9 seconds to execute. However, I would like it to execute every second, including the time it took to run that function.
I don't know the exact processing time within the function; it could take 0.9, 0.92, 0.88,... seconds, so I can't simply use `time.sleep(0.1)`.

I could time the function and substract that from the sleep time, like so:

```
def function(*args, **kwargs):
   start = time.time()
   ## Some processing happens here that takes 0.9 seconds
   end = time.time()
   sleep_time = 1 - (end-start)
   time.sleep(sleep_time)
```

However, doesn't timing the code and doing the substraction in itself take processing time, meaning that the total function takes a little more than 1 second and the schedule will be incorrect after a while?

This seems like something I could accomplish using Threading, however I've always learned that you shouldn't include threading unless you absolutely need it to speed up your runtime, and in my case it won't...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean something like:

```
def do_work():
    print("I am working")

def work_loop():
    while True:
        do_work()
        time.sleep(1)
```

This way your "do_work()" function is executed every 1 seconds plus whatever it takes for your do_work() function to do its work.

Or do you want to run your function every 1 seconds, so if it takes like 0.9 seconds for `do_work()` to finish, you want to restart it after 0.1 seconds?

You could do that by checking the time with something like:

```
def do_work():
    finish_time = int(time.time()) + 1
    # do your calculations in here
    while int(time.time()) < finish_time:
        time.sleep(0.001)
    return
```

I would definitely suggest that you use asyncio for that kind of requirement. Otherwise your programm will just block while it is waiting.

Comment: Your second code sample is indeed a solution to what I want to do, thanks for that. Don't know why I didn't think of it myself... It seems like such a common problem though that I expected some built-in functionality or custom packages that can handle this without using while loops

Comment: One thing I forgot, if you want your do_work() to take approx. 1 second, you should not call int(time.time()). Because that can lead to your do_work() function to run for less than 1 second. Just do a time.time() + 1.

Comment: The second answer works, however int(time.time()) < finish_time should simply be time.time()<finish_time. Else the rounding errors cause it to run for quite a bit more than a second